# В stringstream сохраняется не текст, а адрес

Tags: c++

Вот код. Пользователь вводит строку, потом я из этой строки получаю последнее слово и сохраняю его посимвольно в stringstream. В stringstream сохраняется адрес, а не буквы.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    string a[10]; 
    stringstream b[10]; 
    for(int i = 0; i<10; ++i) {
        getline(cin, a[i]);
        int temp = 0;
        for(int i2 = 0; i2<a[i].length()-1; ++i2) { 
        if(a[i][i2]==' ') {
            temp = i2;
        }
        for(int i2 = temp; i2<a[i].length()-1; ++i2) { 
            b[i] << a[i][i2];
        }
    }
}
    cout << b[1];

}
```

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream

Comment: *"В stringstream сохраняется адрес, а не буквы."* - почему вы так решили?

Answer (score 0):

```
cout << b[1];
```

Что вы выводите? по сути, объект `stringstream` (вспомним `stringstream b[10];`), для которого **нет** оператора вывода, так что *видимо* (у меня на VC++2017 это просто не компилируется) выполняется приведение типов - к `void*`.

Попробуйте выводить

```
cout << b[1].str();
```